# how to extend javascript classes

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Why Child class doesn't have echo() method?

```
Parent = function(){
    this.name = 'abc';
}

Parent.prototype.echo = function(){
    alert(this.name);
}

Child = function(){
    $.extend(this,  Parent);
}

var x = new Child();

x.echo();
```

What should I do to inherit from parent class in Javascript?

Comment: Is this using jQuery? Subclassing in 'plain' javascript does not work this way.

Comment: Throwing the jQuery `$.extend` in there just confuses the hell out of everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the prototype of `Child` to `Parent`.

```
function Parent() {
    this.name = 'abc';
}

Parent.prototype.echo = function () {
    alert(this.name);
}

function Child() {

}

Child.prototype = new Parent()

var x = new Child();

x.echo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use jQuery. The jQuery extend system uses objects, not 'classes', see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

- There are no 'classes' in javascript, only objects and prototypal inheritance
- Parent, Child are not classes, they are functions(as well as objects)
- Within Child, 'this' refers to the global object('window' for browsers)
- use `Child.prototype = new Parent()`